# using map function to square a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list which I want to square each of them.

this is what I have done

```
def square(x):
    return x*x

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
squares = map(square, numbers)


squares_as_strings = str(squares)


print(','.join(squares_as_strings))
```

but the answer is this

```
[,1,,, ,4,,, ,9,,, ,1,6,,, ,2,5,,, ,3,6,]
```

instead of

```
[1,4,9,16,25,36]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You map the `square` function, but you're not mapping the `str` function.  Your `squares_as_strings` is one string, of the entire list.

Change `str(squares)` to `map(str, squares)`.

Comment: I don't understand why `str` is even needed here. The result is given straight from `map`. If this is Python 3 all you need is `list(map(square, numbers))`.

Answer (score 5):

Just solve it with simple list comprehension.

```
squares = [i*i for i in numbers]
```

Or, using map:

```
squares = map(lambda x:x*x,numbers)
```

Comment: Im not allowed to, I have to use map function

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in these lines:

```
squares_as_strings = str(squares)
print(','.join(squares_as_strings))
```

Applying `str` to the `squares` array does not make each number a string.
Instead it gives this - `'[1, 2, 3]'`, which is a string, not an array of strings as you want.

Now, you are `join`-ing it, which results in a comma between each character.

You should instead do:

```
squares = map(str, map(square, numbers))
```

This would make each element of the `squares` array a string. And then use your join.

---

```
def square(x):
    return x * x

nums = [1, 2, 3]
squares = map(str, map(square, nums))

print(','.join(squares))
```

Comment: this is what i got [,',1,',,, ,',4,',,, ,',9,',,, ,',1,6,',,, ,',2,5,',,, ,',3,6,',]

Comment: You made some mistake, because I tested it aswell.

Answer (score 1):

```
def square(x):
        return x*x

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
squares = map(square, numbers)

print(str(squares)) #str() in not needed
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are calling a `join` on a string and not on a `list`. Ultimately, you are not handling the result of your `map` properly.

If you are using Python 2, your map will give you a list, so simply print out `squares` and you will have your expected result.

If you are using Python 3, you will actually have a map object, so you will need to call `list` on it, to obtain a list of your map result:

```
list(squares)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `map` function, you can use:

```
squares = list(map(square, numbers))
```

The `map` function will return a `map` object.

Comment: That's true in Python 3, but it's clear he's not using Python 3.  That is not his problem.

Comment: From where is that apparent?  I might be missing something.

Comment: If you run his program under Python 2, you get exactly the output he shows.  If you run his program under Python 3, you get very different output.

Answer (score -2):

##how to increment to 10 in nums except we type manual

```
def square(x):
    return x*x

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
squares = map(square, numbers)
squares_as_strings = str(squares)  

print(','.join(squares_as_strings))
```

Comment: This prints `<,m,a,p, ,o,b,j,e,c,t, ,a,t, ,0,x,0,0,0,0,0,1,D,6,5,8,2,F,1,0,B,8,>`. Please test your code before submitting.

Comment: There are two issues with this code: 1. Remove `str(squares)`; `squares` is a Map object and it needs to be evaluated to get the list of squares like: `squares = list(squares)`. 2. You can now use the list of squares as is: `print(','.join(squares))`